# Paypal Sandbox doing crazy things

Tags: paypal-sandbox

First of all , the test accounts I created were not working. So, I removed all Paypal cookies.So, now good thing I can login into test accounts but can't access My Settings and My Selling tools under My Profile. I'm trying to create Buy Now button in My Selling tools.

Also, My Paypal live account is for Paypal Payments Standard(My Business Setup->My payment solution) and in test account the payment solution is Paypal Payments Pro and doesn't let me change this option.The links in my business solution (View all products to learn more or select an additional payment solution or we can recommend one that fits your needs.) goes to PayPal live site.

Any one facing this crazy PayPal sandbox behavior !!!

Answer (score 0):

When you say you can't access My Settings and My Selling tools under My Profile, are you getting an error or what is it doing specifically.  The Pro account that you have in sandbox, will work for testing Website Payments Standard.  Also, another option if you can't create test buttons from your sandbox account would be to log into your live account and create a non hosted / clear text button.  Then you would just modify the button code, and change the URL in the form tag from the live site to the sandbox site.  Also, you will need to change the value of the business variable and set it to either the email address of your test sandbox seller account or the merchant id.  Another work around that has worked in the past as well, is going into your live account and going to the page you are wanting and copy the URL from the address bar and just modifing it to include the sandbox URL.

So if my live site URL was something like:

```
https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_flow&SESSION=
```

I would just change it to

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_flow&SESSION=
```

Also, if you can give me more details about what is happening when you try to access your profile in your sandbox account I can look into it further.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. On  accessing My Settings and My Selling tools, I 'm not getting any error message but it keeps searching for the page infinitely. Also, If I copy the link location of My Settings, My Selling tools and paste in into new tab/window, the browser can't find the server. URL for My Settings : https://www.beta-sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-display-handler&tab_id=ACCOUNT_SETTINGS

Comment: There is currently a bug open for this issue that we are working to resolve.  You could try accessing the page you are trying to get to directly by pulling up that same page in your live account and then modifying the URL to point to the sandbox like I mentioned above.

Comment: @PP_MTS_Chad - I've experienced both the permanent "loading twiddly" and getting bounce unexpectedly to the live site numerous times.  (I assume that there's no problem getting a real refund for activity that should have stayed in the sandbox, but didn't.)  Would you mind posting all of the URLs used on the live site for those of us trying to do development, but lacking a live Payments Pro account to cut'n'paste from?

Comment: I do not have a full list of the URL's for every page as there are several different links through out your account.  I typically just grab them them as I need them from my live account.  Keep in mind that this works most of the time but not all of the time.